# Overpayment of 2021 Economic Impact Payment (the third stimulus)

Tags: united-states, taxes, stimulus

Odd situation. My son was a dependent on our 2019 return but not 2020. We both filed our 2020 returns a few days before the EIPs began -- my wife and I as joint filers (minus one dependent--our son) and our son as a non-dependent single filer. The following week my wife and I received the EIP with our son still counted as a dependent. Then our son received his own payment. Clearly the IRS based our payment on our 2019 return and our son's on 2020. So as a family we were paid twice for him. Of course, we shouldn't keep the extra $1400, but will the IRS expect reimbursement? And by what means? Just a weird deal all around, and I am not sure what to do. Any thoughts?

Comment: A good question that seems to have up a few times already! Please do flag to reopen if you think the existing linked question isn't the same.